# Understanding: Separable space definition

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone explain how existence of countable dense subset imply , there exists a sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$   of elements of the space such that every nonempty open subset of the space contains at least one element of the sequence.

Comment: This would be the definitions of "dense" and "countable".

Comment: If some open non empty set did not intersect with the $x_n$ then it would not be dense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq X$ an countable dense subset. As $A$ is countable, there is a surjection $f \colon \mathbf N \to A$. Define $x_n := f(n) \in X$. Now let $U \subseteq X$ a non-empty open subset of $X$. As $A$ is dense, we have then $\bar A = X$, therefore $X \setminus A$ has non-empty interior and therefore we must have $U \not\subseteq X \setminus A$ or $U \cap A \ne \emptyset$. Choose $n \in \mathbf N$ such that $f(n) \in U \cap A$. Then $x_n \in U$.